# Can I set the GLSL version?

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I'm trying to figure out if I can set the GLSL version used in OpenGL 2.1. So far it works with some generic immediate mode shaders, but I'd like to use modern OpenGL shaders. Any ideas on how I can?

Comment: Check http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/opengl-setup-for-glsl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the version on GLSL to use as the first statement of your shader:

```
#version 330 compatibility

#version 420 core
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks! But also, would this break compatibility with older cards?

Comment: @AlexLarsen: Yes and no... GLSL version is defined by the driver version, and while it is true that overall a greater version of GLSL has greater hardware requirements sometimes the same hardware can run newer GLSL shaders simply by upgrading drivers. The most compatible modern GLSL version these days would be 320 (given a modern driver), DX10 class hardware (most cards mfg.'d after ~2007) supports 320. Technically they would support 330 too, but to support OS X you should limit yourself to 320.